# How to pass '#' character to ACTION_DIAL intent in Android

Tags: android

I want to pass a number include "#" to the Android system's dialer pad. Like the following code I used:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:#123456#"));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

But actually, the number displayed in the dialer pad is "123456", the "#" has disappeared.
I can't find what caused this problem, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", "#123456#", "#")); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("#123456#"));

mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to DIAL a number (for example: #123) you can try this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("#123")));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

If you want to make a CALL to a number like #123, you just modify the Intent:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("#123")));
startActivity(callIntent);
```